# CHECK CONSTRAINT ERROR USING SQL MANAGEMENT STUDIO

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SALES]
(
    [SaleID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID(), 
    [ProductID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WorkID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Quantity] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [SaleDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_SaleDate DEFAULT (GETDATE())
    CONSTRAINT CHK_QuantitySaleDate CHECK (Quantity > 0 AND DATEDIFF (d,GETDATE(), SaleDate) <=0)

) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Trying to execute the above query results in the following error:

```
"Column CHECK constraint for column 'SaleDate' references another column, table 'SALES'."
```

Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: The columns I'm referencing on the column level CHECK CONSTRAINT reside in the same table. I do have other CHECK constraints in other tables I've created, which work well. By the way I'm new to sql, please bear with me

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are setting constraint as COLUMN constraint. You have to set it as TABLE constraint. So, after:

```
[SaleDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_SaleDate DEFAULT (GETDATE())
```

you need a comma sign, so it should be:

```
[SaleDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_SaleDate DEFAULT (GETDATE()),
CONSTRAINT...
```